# Create an event for a Public Group using Office 365 API

Tags: ios, office365

As the title: How can i create an event for a Public Group using Office 365 REST API? Note: I can create event for an user now.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the group alias email address to the event while creating it as an attendee. everyone will get notified by email and they can add it to their individual calendars.

Check out this link for creating an event with attendees.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#EventResource

Hope this helps.